# Can LINQ ForEach have if statement?

Tags: c#, linq, list, if-statement, foreach

Is it possible to add `if`-statement inside LINQ `ForEach` call?

```
sequence.Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Apple"))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach( /* If statement here */ );
```

Comment: The question isn't clear

Comment: There is no LINQ `ForEach` method. That is a method of `List`.

Comment: What would you want to put in the `if` that can't be used as predicate in the `Where`?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can do the following...

```
List.Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Apple")).ToList()
    .ForEach( x => { if(x.Name == ""){}} );
```

Answer (score 38):

Yes, if-statement is commonly used inside the ForEach as below:

```
sequence.Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Apple"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach( x =>
     {
       if(someCondition)
       {
         // Do some stuff here.
       }  
     });
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It takes a lambda expressions, so you can put any valid c# expression in there

Comment: I wouldn't say _any_... There are some constructs that the expression API cannot represent.

Comment: Oh wait sorry, my comment doesn't apply here. We're creating a delegate here, not an expression. IIRC, the same restrictions doesn't affect delegates, any construct may be used.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread but throwing an in my opinion cleaner syntax

```
foreach(var item in sequence.Where(s => s.Name.ToString() == "Apple"))
{
 // do whatever
}
```

Comment: True, Linq vs traditional foreach should be used for the sake of simplicity, i.e Whatever looks cleaner and easier to understand should be used.

Comment: If Linq with lambda could shrink long foreach to single line it can be used. But if Linq is becoming too unreadable then traditional foreach can be used for better readability.